# Separate Boiler & AC system and WiFi thermostat

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

Wiring to Honeywell T9 WiFi thermostat. Have separate hot water boiler and separate Trane AC air handler to outside compressor. Trane AH has no board only colored wires Blue Green Red
Where is the common to power the Thermostat?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the wiring diagram for the AH?

Comment: Also, can you post photos of your boiler's wiring diagram please?

Comment: At a minimum, provide the exact models of equipment involved. Best we can do with the info provided is join you in making random guesses.